# Is it ok to call dadline_timer object after its destruction

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Is it ok to write the following code?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service g_io;

void foo(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  {
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(g_io, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(3000));
    timer.async_wait(
      boost::bind(
        foo,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error
      )
    );
  }

  g_io.run();
}
```

Note that the `timer` object will be destructed before its call. Is it ok or should I use something like `std::shared_ptr` here?

Comment: Unless you can find a cast-iron, copper-bottomed, guarantee in the boost docs that they make this work, I would use a shared_ptr and not worry about it.

Comment: A shared pointer won't really help here because it will go out of scope just like the original object, taking whatever it points to with it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`deadline_timer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) is a typedef of [`basic_deadline_timer< boost::posix_time::ptime >`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer.html). `basic_deadline_timer` inherits the [`basic_io_object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object.html). The [destructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/_basic_io_object.html) of `basic_io_object` performs

```
get_service().destroy(get_implementation());
```

So, when `timer` goes out of scope, it's implementation will be passed to `destroy` member function of it's associated service.

The documentation doesn't seem to state explicitly (or I can't find where), but as far as I know, `deadline_timer` must conform to the [WaitableTimerService](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/WaitableTimerService.html) concept. It asserts

> `a.destroy(b);`  Implicitly cancels asynchronous wait operations, as if by calling a.cancel(b, e).

and

> `a.cancel(b, e);` Causes any outstanding asynchronous wait operations to complete as soon as possible. Handlers for cancelled operations shall be passed the error code error::operation_aborted. Sets e to indicate success or failure. Returns the number of operations that were cancelled.

So, it appears to be OK in the sense that the destroyed timer won't be referenced by an asynchronous task so there won't be UB.

It appears to be not OK in the sense that the asynchronous operations will not wait for the deadline, and will be cancelled, rather than executed normally.